# Help to markdown editing

Tags: bug, markdown, help-center

There are wrong examples of usage, and for newbie this can be confusing.

Everywhere are:

```
__italic__ or **bold**
```

but that is wrong because result of this is:

> **italic** or **bold**

Should be:

```
*italic* or **bold**
```

or

```
*italic* or __bold__
```

What gives:
*italic* or **bold**

Comment: Where did you see the first example?

Comment: It's not `__italic__ or **bold**`, it's `_italic_ or **bold**`, which does indeed yield "_italic_ or **bold**".

Comment: Wow, I'm blind :D I haven't noticed there is no two chars... So, there is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you've seen these "wrong" examples. The basic rule is that one is italic and two is bold:

- `_italic1_` and `*italic2*` :  *italic1* and *italic2*
- `__bold1__` and `**bold2**` : **bold1** and **bold2**

Finally, three means italic *and* bold:

`***italic & bold***` and `___italic & bold___` : ***italic & bold*** and ***italic & bold***

That's exactly what is shown in the [formatting help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) page.

Comment: Wow, I'm blind :D I haven't noticed there is no two chars... So, there is no problem.